# Is there a way to use global_step in Keras framework?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to reproduce `polynomial decay` for `learning rate decay` in `Keras` framework  which as  implemented in `Tensorflow` framework is given below.

```
def poly_decay(step, initial_value, decay_period_images_seen):
    """
    Decays a variable using a polynomial law.
    :param step: number of images seen by the network since the beginning of the training.
    :param initial_value: The initial value of the variable to decay..
    :param decay_period_images_seen: the decay period in terms of images seen by the network
    (1 epoch of 10 batches of 6 images each means that 1 epoch = 60 images seen).
    Thus this value must be a multiple of the number of batches
    :return: The decayed variable.
    """

    factor = 1.0 - (tf.cast(step, tf.float32) / float(decay_period_images_seen))
    lrate = initial_value * np.power(factor, 0.9)

    return lrate
```

Does Keras offer any hidden parameter (which perhaps I don't know about) for `global step` or is there an equivalent of `global step` in Keras?  Or is there any alternative way to implement `polynomial learning rate decay` in `Keras` framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the parameter is itself provided as arguments for `optimisers`.

Take a look at [optimizers](https://keras.io/optimizers/).

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)
```

So here, you can just pass in the `poly_decay()` as a parameter.

Usually we use `time-based decay` instead of `polynomial decay`:

```
learning_rate = 0.1
decay_rate = learning_rate / epochs
momentum = 0.8
sgd = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, decay=decay_rate, nesterov=False)
```

Check this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-rate-schedules-and-adaptive-learning-rate-methods-for-deep-learning-2c8f433990d1) for more reference!!